Streamlit - rapid update map (folium / geopandas)
I have this code which should update the coordinates (lat, lon and status of gps fix) rapidly via streamlit:
import socket
import struct
import time
import threading
import streamlit as st
import folium
from streamlit.runtime.scriptrunner import add_script_run_ctx
from streamlit_folium import st_folium

SERVER_ADDRESS = '127.0.0.1'
SERVER_PORT = 25567
LAT_LON_PRECISION = 8

STATUS_NO_FIX = -1  # unable to fix position
STATUS_FIX = 0  # unaugmented fix
STATUS_SBAS_FIX = 1  # with satellite-based augmentation
STATUS_GBAS_FIX = 2


@st.cache_resource
def getSharedData():
    return {
        'latitude': None,
        'longitude': None,
        'status': None
    }


def receiveData(shared_data):
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    client.bind((SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT))
    while True:
        data, server_address = client.recvfrom(1024)
        unpacked_data = struct.unpack('ddi', data)
        latitude, longitude, status = unpacked_data

        shared_data['latitude'] = round(latitude, LAT_LON_PRECISION)
        shared_data['longitude'] = round(longitude, LAT_LON_PRECISION)
        shared_data['status'] = getStatusText(status)


@st.cache_resource
def updateData():
    receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receiveData, args=(getSharedData(),))
    receive_thread.daemon = True
    add_script_run_ctx(receive_thread)
    receive_thread.start()


def getStatusText(status):
    if status == STATUS_NO_FIX:
        return "No Fix"
    elif status == STATUS_FIX:
        return "Fix"
    elif status == STATUS_SBAS_FIX:
        return "SBAS"
    elif status == STATUS_GBAS_FIX:
        return "GBAS"
    return "N/A"


def main():
    st.set_page_config(layout="wide")
    updateData()

    sharedData = getSharedData()

    lat_display = st.empty()
    lon_display = st.empty()
    status_display = st.empty()
    map_display = st.empty()
    
    m = folium.Map(zoom_start=12)

    while True:
        latitude = sharedData['latitude']
        longitude = sharedData['longitude']
        status = sharedData['status']
        if latitude is None or longitude is None:
            time.sleep(0.075)
            continue
        lat_display.text(f"Latitude: {latitude}")
        lon_display.text(f"Longitude: {longitude}")
        status_display.text(f"Status: {status}")

        folium.Marker([latitude, longitude], tooltip="Current Location").add_to(m)

        with map_display:
            st_folium(m)

        time.sleep(0.075)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I have finally got data sharing / caching working across multiple clients.
The issue I have now is that I want to render a map with the current location (and more stuff in the future). But when I do the st_folium call (same with geopandas and st.map()) it start to flicker. How can I rapidly update a map? Any sort of map, I dont have to stick to folium or geopandas.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

and show code which makes problem - so we could copy and test it.

Sorry, i have made the code easier to test and use, and ive dug a bit more into it and found out that the socket bind call, or the more the main method is getting executed multiple times. I hope its more clear now :)

Brother of coworker suggested plotly_chart. Works like a charm.
New version 1.35.0 bricks it, works with version 1.34.0 and below.
